# Clarification on scope delegation of dockerExposedPorts with sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using the sbt-native-packager plugin that comes with Scala Play:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.8")
```

I would like to know why the `dockerExposedPorts` setting isn't set for the `root` project when using:

```scala
name := """scala-play-react-seed"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    Docker / dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000), // <-- 1. doesn't work
  )

Docker / dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000), // <-- 2. also doesn't work
```

```sh
$ sbt show root/dockerExposedPorts
[info] *
```

However, it works if i remove the `Docker` config part:

```scala
  .settings(
    dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000), // <-- 3. works
  )
```

```sh
$ sbt show root/dockerExposedPorts
[info] * 9000
```

As far is i understand sbt's [scope delegation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html), case 1. is scoped as `root / Docker / Zero / dockerExposedPorts`, which should be more specific than case 3. `root / Zero / Zero / dockerExposedPorts`. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Docker / dockerExposedPorts` is more specific than `Zero / dockerExposedPorts`. But unlike what you seem to assume, it's the more specific scopes that delegate to the less specific ones, not the other way around. The manual says so:

> This feature allows you to set a value once in a more general scope, allowing multiple more-specific scopes to inherit the value.

And in fact, this is the only way it could be, because you might define e. g. both  `Docker / dockerExposedPorts` and `Universal / dockerExposedPorts`. Which one of these would `Zero / dockerExposedPorts` delegate to? There's no sensible answer to that, hence delegation goes in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks. So as i understand we have to separate setting a value in a scope from "looking up" a value in a scope. With `Docker / dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000)` we set the value in a narrow specific scope. When we want to look up the value `Zero / dockerExposedPorts`, it's within a less specific scope (with no value set) and can delegate/look up in even less specific scopes, and never reach `Docker / dockerExposedPorts`. Is that correct?